# Доступ alias к скрытым файлам(dotfiles)

Tags: php, linux, nginx, apache, битрикс

На сервере (Centos 7) настроен алиас через апач с подпапки /ru/ на корневую папку.
Выглядит так:

```
Alias /ru /home/bitrix/ext_www/s1
```

Настройки директории:

```
<Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/s1>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Папка нужна для реализации мультиязычности на подпапках.
Проблема в том, что скрытые файлы алиасу не видны. Сайт на битриксе, и файлы по типу .top_menu.php или .section.php просто не видны. Отсюда проблемы с отсутвием меню, заголовков и т.д.
Можно как-то дополнить конфиг, чтобы по пути /home/bitrix/ext_www/s1/ru/ была полная копия папки /home/bitrix/ext_www/s1 включая все скрытые файлы и подпапки?